# If a "Utilities" class is evil, where do I put my generic code?

Tags: c#, oop, global-variables, utility-method

I generally live by the rule that Global variables / functions are evil and that every piece of code should live in the class to which it pertains.

This is a very easy rule to follow, and I believe that I haven't ever run into an issue with this rule until now.

Today, however, I need to add a function to my *assembly* rather than to a specific class.  That is, almost all of my classes *could* have a use for this particular function.

**Where should I put this function (+1 overload)?**

If I put it in a "Utilities" class, I feel dirty.  If I tack it on to a semi-related class, and let other classes call it directly, I feel worse.

This particular piece of code basically chops a `IList<PointF>` into a normalized list.  I feel right now that adding it as an extension method on `IList<PointF>` may be the best bet...

Comment: I agree, global variables are evil. They seem to have minds of their own devoted to undermining your code.

Comment: Global state is problematic, but global functions are just logic that's reusable with too few ins/outs to be worth encapsulating in a class.  I don't see any problem at all with Helper or Utility methods grouped into appropriately named Helper or Utility static classes.

Comment: I prefer using "Pull Up Method" instead of Utility/Helper class - [Pull Up Method](https://refactoring.guru/pull-up-method)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If this is an operation on an `IList<PointF>`, then it should be an extension method on `IList<PointF>`.

Generally, `Utils` and `Helper` type classes should be avoided. More often than not, you will find that what you may *think* is a utility method, is actually a rather specific method that probably belongs in a class of its own (just like you say). However, there will be domain specific cases where `Util`-like classes (classes which group related useful methods) are valid entities.

Comment: +1 Extension methods are perfect for this kind of problem

Comment: Yeah, but my reservation here is that if it is an extension, then it needs to have a fluent sounding name... something like `points.NormalizeIntoSegments(50)`, instead of my preferred `Utilities.Segment(points, 50)`.

Comment: what about class NormalizedIList extends IList?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but if `Utilities.Segment(points, 50)` is fine, what's wrong with `points.Segment(50)`?

Comment: @Diadistis What is an extension method?

Comment: @KorayTugay [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

Comment: Extension methods and static utility methods are actually the same thing. The **only** difference is the method call syntax, where the first argument to a extension method is placed before the `.` operator. The way you use extension methods and static utility methods to design software is exactly the same. I find it confusing that this answer seems to imply that there is a difference.

Comment: I am from Java world. I have a rule. If I want to add functionalities to a API class e.g Date, String I create a specific Util class. like DateUtil, StringUtil. Otherwise, as you said most of the util method are later found it's belong to a class.

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing wrong with "global" variables and methods. You use them all the time. The framework likes to call them "static" classes or "static" methods.

I rarely need to, but I usually add an internal static class Util in the namespace that the method/variable is needed for C# and a module for VB.NET.

Samples from .NET Framework

- `System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionsUtil`
- `System.Net.WebUtility`
- Check Microsoft's source code for .NET Framework. You will find numerous internal utility classes.

Comment: Notice that all the examples from the BCL are grouped around a particular responsibility.  There's no generic `Utils` class anywhere.

Comment: What is BCL? Do you mean Base Class Libraries (BCL)?

Comment: Open *.NET Reflector*. Search for "util". There are 256 examples using the default (BCL) 4.0 assemblies loaded by *.NET Reflector*.

Answer (score 4):

You should put it into a 'ListUtilities' or `PointListUtilities` class, of course.  Then you aren't breaking the single responsibility principle, which is the primary problem with a catch-all 'Utilities' class.