# Best design practice with using methods that multiple fragments use

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing an Android unit conversion and calculator application in which I have a 3 fragment ViewPager set up and was wondering what would be the best OOP design practice when attempting to use methods over many fragments. Should I set up a centralized calculate method and call it within each fragment?

I currently have each fragment isolated with their calculations, spinner values, and intermediary values. I am also sending a result of a calculation from a fragment back to another fragment through an intent on the Main Activity.

My code currently works, but as I am learning more Java I would like to start piecing together best design practices and efficient code. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I would suggest creating a Utility class, but be careful that you don't needlessly throw all your methods in it. Read over this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340032/utility-classes-are-evil

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will thoroughly read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, i'd write something like  `CalculationUtils.java` and define every common method inside, as `public static`, and later call them with `CalculationUtils.method1(...)`

Comment: That's great. Exactly what I was looking for, but I could not express into words.