# Why "Procedure Class" is a Design Smell?

Tags: refactoring

In "A systematic literature review on the detection of smells and their evolution in object‐oriented and service‐oriented systems" research paper, procedure class is identified as a smell. But there is not definition given and the reference also do not contain any description or information about it.

So can anybody tell why procedure class is a smell and how it can be refactored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also unable to find any mention of the phrase "procedure class" or anything similar in either of the references cited by this paper. It seems problematic that the paper cites two sources yet neither source actually uses that phrase. I would be very suspicious of a paper's results when its sources are in question.

Without direct references, my assumption is the phrase "procedure class" is an alternative form of *utility class*. It can be considered an OO anti-pattern as in these posts.

- https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-utility-classes/
- https://ralin.io/blog/oop-anti-patterns-utility-or-helper-classes.html
- https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html
- [Utility classes are evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340032/utility-classes-are-evil)