# Passing object to constructor versus getting from static utility class

Tags: java, oop, instance-variables, utility-method

I am not sure how to design of my Java classes, the question is also related to better testing.

I am using static utility class/method `Utils.getMapper()` to get configured `ObjectMapper` at many places in my Spring application.

When object mapper is needed, e.g. in `@Service` class, should I pass the instance via constructor parameter only or is correct to get mapper in my class by calling utility method?

Comment: related: [Are utility classes evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3340032/1371329)

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to pass the `ObjectMapper` instance via constructor parameter in your `@Service` class instead of calling the utility method to get the instance.

By passing the instance via constructor parameter, you can ensure that the `ObjectMapper` instance is provided explicitly to your class, which makes your class's dependencies more explicit and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ObjectMapper bean and inject it via constructor into your classes.