# How do I share lots of unrelated methods between different classes without creating a "god namespace/static class"?

Tags: c#, namespaces, static-class

A "God Namespace" is the (uncommon) term for an (anti?)pattern analogous to the "God Object", when you stuff a metric ton of stuff (mostly methods/functions) that is not related or not closely related to each other into one huge namespace/`static class` just so that it can be used in multiple sections of your project.

When following that (anti?)pattern, you often end up, as a C# example, with something like a `static class Assets` with tons of methods mostly unrelated to each other, but used across multiple places in your project(s).

I usually approach this problem by letting the next `Assets` grow for as much as I can bear it, and then desperately try to sort its contents out into several smaller ones based on the criteria which seems most legit, like `MathAssets`, or `BitmapAssets`, or `RNGAssets`, and then end up forgetting what did I put where... and make a new `Assets` for several new methods which don't fit into either of the `SomethingAssets` already cluttering up the project.

Are there any other ways of clearing up the "God Namespace"? Or will I just have to live with good old `static class Assets`?

Comment: This has been asked (I'm sure) many times before.  Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339929/if-a-utilities-class-is-evil-where-do-i-put-my-generic-code

Comment: @roryap: thanks, I must have been searching with the wrong keywords! =) I guess this should be re-closed as a duplicate...

Comment: Jon sonmez have a series of articles regarding this subject. [Here is the introduction](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/04/12/should-i-leave-that-helper-class/) and [read this](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/04/14/how-to-refactor-the-helper-class/)