# respecting the DRY principle for variable containing the class name

Tags: java, dry

How do you set variables which contain the class name, like `TAG` in `android.util.Log`, while respecting Dont-Repeat-Yourself?

These are some possibilities:

In **Google code**, it is often used like

```
public class Classname {
    public final String TAG = "Classname";
```

which repeats the classname and was not refactor-renamed correctly in AndroidStudio (no `String`s were).

Then, there is a **dynamic variant**

```
public class Classname {
    public final String TAG = getClass().getName();
```

which does not repeat the Classname, thus seems better, yet is less readable.

Or, you could **make TAG `static`** (this might be premature optimization). Apart from the official version above, you could get the name in code like

```
public class Classname {
    public final static String TAG 
       = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName();
```

which is way less readable, and does have problems with inheritance (being static).

What is the best practice concerning this?

Is there a better way than 1-3? (Or is this a wrong approach?)

Comment: You're free to do as you want. DRY is a principle, it's not a law that requires you to bend over backwards to try to avoid writing the same sequence of letters twice.

Comment: What about `public final static String TAG = Classname.class.getName();`, this should be refactored correctly ?

Comment: @Kayaman: It seems inelegant to repeat the classname. Sure, it's not a law, but if the code could be better ...

Comment: @user1587329 Java isn't exactly the go-to (goto?) language for elegant code in the first place.

Comment: A better solution would be for the logger to determine the class name so that there would be no need for TAG. I've written a logger wrapper that works this way.

Comment: @user1587329: [ClassLogger](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/log/ClassLogger.html) in my ORM project, [sormula](http://www.sormula.org), does this. Also see [project in bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jeff43017/sormula/overview). It is not written for Android but I am sure it could be adapted for Android.

Comment: @FlorentBayle: that works in a `static` context, which is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone with the dynamic approach in the past:

```
public class Classname {
     public final String TAG = getClass().getName();
```

It is not *that* unreadable, and it is self-contained.

For more complex cases of DRY-ness, there is always the possibility of creating your own annotations, and then either

- Use a two-step compile process to first generate non-DRY sources and then compile them into non-DRY .class files.
- Use the annotations in an initialization step within your program to fill in the non-DRY parts at run-time, before running any logic that depends on those parts.

Using the second approach, you could have something like

```
@ReplaceWithClassName("TAG")
public class Classname {
     public final String TAG;
```

And then you would iterate through all classes annotated with `@ReplaceWithClassName` filling in the blanks as an initialization step (more on iterating through annotated classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime); more on changing a final String [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)).

Annotations, introspection and code-generation provide great flexibility and power. Therefore, use wisely if you use them at all. For this particular case, the "dynamic approach" is much more readable.

Comment: How would you approach `final static String TAG`? (f.ex. in a utility class?) (or do you avoid all utility classes, as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339929/if-a-utilities-class-is-evil-where-do-i-put-my-generic-code?](evil)

Comment: the link on "more on changing a final String" demonstrates how to  change a  `private static final` one - so it *is* possible to do this via introspection using run-time annotations as part of an initialization step. On the other hand, I would still prefer "way 3" from your original question. Read on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt - avoiding debt is good, but your programming time is limited. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the annotation possibility, the assurance to use the dynamic approach and the reminder to Keep It Simple Stupid (and the Wiki link saying that the original is *without a comma*). (The `private static final` approach had so many warning signs that using it in production code without *having to* seems overkill)

Answer (score 1):

#### retrieve class name dynamically

@JeffMiller gave the example in the ClassLogger class of his sormula project. In the class [`Logger`](https://bitbucket.org/jeff43017/sormula/src/b4925935fea920d06406ebc03717a9a0bddcfd5c/src/main/java/org/sormula/log/ClassLogger.java?at=default), he uses

```
StackTraceElement[] stes =  new Throwable().getStackTrace();
int e = stes.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < e; ++i) {
    if (stes[i].getClassName().equals(classLoggerClassName)) {
        // next on stack is the class that created me
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(stes[i + 1].getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

to get the caller's class name.

#### use the class to get its name

@FlorentBayle said in the comments that

```
public final static String TAG = Classname.class.getName();
```

should be refactored correctly. (And is more readable than variant 3 above).

This is also the approach used by third-party logging frameworks like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). It is initialized via

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
```

Comment: Use this to initialize log wrapper per class. classLoggerClassName in this example is log wrapper class name, org.sormula.log.Logger. RoboGuice looks promising. I will investigate it for my next Android app.

Comment: @JeffMiller: RoboGuice use seems discouraged by Google: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html. See f.ex. this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194283/does-avoid-dependency-injection-frameworks-in-the-android-memory-guide-apply-t/24194366#24194366